# Why does my apache refuse the "Content-Security-Policy" headers?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, http-headers

I'm currently in the process of implementing Content-Security-Policies. But my apache refused to accept the config settings.

The apache2 versions I am currently using are: 2.2.22 and 2.4.7. Neither of those apache2 versions seem to work.

My config settings are:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self' *.google.de google.de *.google.com google.com;
Header always set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; report-uri https://www.myhostname.com/report/report.php;
Header always set X-Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self' google.de google.com;
```

I receive the following error message on either of those settings. If I comment out one line, the error just changes to the following line:

```
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf:
Header has too many arguments
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I've tried every possible combination of settings, resulting in the same error messages. So I come to believe, that my apaches don't support those headers? But I haven't found anything on the web regarding this issue.

Or am I just missing something crucial? I have also copied various examples from other pages and they produced the same errors.

Headers in general are working fine. I have a couple of other headers set, which work perfectly:

```
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "master-only"
Header always set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header always set Pragma "no-cache"
Header always set Expires "-1"
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the value of the header contains spaces, you must surround it in double quotes. Your examples already do this, but your intended new headers do not.

For example, you tried:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self' *.google.de google.de *.google.com google.com;
```

It should be:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-src 'self' *.google.de google.de *.google.com google.com;"
```

or you can do this:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: "\
  frame-src 'self' \
     *.google.de   \
       google.de   \
     *.google.com  \
       google.com  \
;"
```