# How do allow fontawesome as a style-src in my Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm trying to set my Content-Security-Policy header in .htaccess.

I've already tried a variation of the answer [to this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/706472/why-does-my-apache-refuse-the-content-security-policy-headers) but it doesnt work. All my fontawesome icons are broken.

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'self'; style-src  *.fontawesome.com"
```

I've also tried using `*.use.fontawesome.com`.

I've tried setting it with a `<meta>` tag in my site `<head>` as well but got the same result.

When using an .htaccess validator I receive the error: "Fatal: Header has too many arguments"

I'm currently receiving this error for this header in particular:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' *.wpengine.com *.hotjar.com; style-src 'self' *.wpengine.com *.fontawesome.com; img-src 'self'; font-src 'self' *.fontawesome *.google.com; connect-src *; media-src *; object-src *; child-src *; frame-src *; worker-src *; frame-ancestors *; form-action *; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; referrer no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header value must be quoted if it is meant to contain whitespace.

Your first example properly quotes the value, but your second example does not.